# WPF Listview binding - Get bound item in code behind

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to access the UserControl's bound object (generated from listView itemsource) from codebehind.

I have the following code:

```
<ListView x:Name="lst1">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
       <Controls:MyUserControl />  
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
<ListView>
```

---

```
public void Load()
{
    lst1.ItemsSource = List<Customer> from database ......
}
```

In each user control that is gererated, I want to access the Customer object that the user control is getting it's values from, ie:

```
public MyUserControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Customer cust = (Customer)this.DataContext;
    // cust is null????
}
```

This code successfully displays properties from the Customer object, I just can't seem to find it in the code behind.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the compiler really let you assign `object` to `Customer` without a cast?

Anyway, `DataContext` won't be initialized yet in the constructor.

You could handle the `DataContextChanged` event, which will be raised whenever `DataContext` changes -- in this case, that'll probably just be when it's assigned in the course of instantiating the `DataTemplate` that creates `MyUserControl`. And that's just what you want.

XAML

```
<UserControl
    ...
    DataContextChanged="MyUserControl_DataContextChanged"
    ...
```

C#

```
private Customer _customer;
void MyUserControl_DataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    _customer = (Customer)DataContext;
}
```

Or you could just cast `DataContext` to `Customer` whenever you need to use it. Check for `null`, of course. You didn't say what you're doing with `Customer` so it's hard to be sure when you would need to do something with it.

Comment: Thanks for spotting that - I've updated question with the cast.

Comment: Thanks for the short and sweet answer.  I didn't know that DataContext wouldn't be available until after construction.  I wasn't planning on using it until a save later on takes place.  Many Thanks again.

Comment: @Noobie3001 If you think about it, nobody can assign anything to it (or any property of any class instance) until after the constructor completes -- other than the new class instance itself, which could only get a value for the DataContext via a parameter to the constructor. But that constructor has no parameters.